# How do I get Maven to emit compile errors like javac does?

Tags: java, maven

In Java if I have in my source code a method call that does not provide the correct parameter types, or if I try to assign to a variable of one type a value of another incompatible type, then this will provoke a compilation error, as it ought to.  But, when using Maven (mvn) the compilation error will be something like (taken from real code)

```
error: method put in interface Map<K,V> cannot be applied to given types;
```

full stop.  Whereas, when using javac (javac) the compilation error will be something like

```
error: method put in interface Map<K,V> cannot be applied to given types;

        elements.put(coords, val);}
                ^
  required: Integer[],T
  found: int[],T
  reason: actual argument int[] cannot be converted to Integer[] by method invocation conversion
  where T,K,V are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in class Grid
    K extends Object declared in interface Map
    V extends Object declared in interface Map
```

I consider this to be more helpful.

How do I get Maven to emit compile errors like javac does?  In particular, how do I get it to provide more contextual information?

The -e and -X switches to mvn do not solve this problem, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using version 2.5.1 or lesser of the Maven Compiler Plugin.

If you use version 3.0, you actually get more detailed error messages:

```
[ERROR] required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
[ERROR] found: int,int
[ERROR] reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to java.lang.String by method    invocation conversion
```

Comment: [Current version is 3.2](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)